# How to send retrieved multiple value array data from view to controller to insert it by loop that add new row until less than count

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is Model

```
public class candidate_votes
{

    public int ff_id_fk { get; set; }
    public int cmember_id { get; set; }
    public int cparty_id { get; set; }
    public int cand_votos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is View that i am showing data to insert this data into db so that data is in multi values means bulkdata i want every row add in db untill count

```
        foreach (var doc in Model)
        {
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Candidate Name</label>
                    <p>@doc.member_name</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmember_id[]" value="@doc.member_id" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Party Name</label>
                    <p>@doc.party_name</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cparty_id[]" value="@doc.party_id_fk" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Total Votes</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cand_votos[]" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Here is controller which i am using to post data and on same time first i get data on view with other controller than i am posting that data to this controller

```
    public ActionResult ps_formForty(candidate_votes cand )
    {
                    Dictionary<string, string> data2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cand.cmember_id.count; i++)
        {
            data2.Add("cmember_id", (cand.cmember_id).ToString());
            data2.Add("cparty_id", cand.cparty_id.ToString());
            data2.Add("cand_votos", cand.cand_votos.ToString());
            DbObject.Insert("candidate_votes", data2);

        }


        return View();
    }
```

i want something like this and but i couuld not apply loop on candidate_votes cand object 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Suggest you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand how to generate form controls for a collection (but then the parameter in your POST method is not even a collection so it not clear what your trying to do)

Comment: The `foreach` loop creates multiple hidden `input` elements with same `name` attribute, which is invalid HTML. You need to use `HiddenFor` and viewmodel indexing to get the model bound into POST method.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen says. You can only loop a collection and not a simple class. You need to return an array from the UI. The C# goes something like this:

```
    public ActionResult ps_formForty(List<candidate_votes> cand )
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> data2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cand.count; i++)
        {
            data2.Add("cmember_id", (cand.cmember_id).ToString());
            data2.Add("cparty_id", cand.cparty_id.ToString());
            data2.Add("cand_votos", cand.cand_votos.ToString());
            DbObject.Insert("candidate_votes", data2);

        }


        return View();
}
```

From the JavaScript, you may pass the array of items.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: array,
   url: url,
   success: function(msg){
     //Your code
   }
});
```

On the other hand, if you do not have an array, and only one object of candidate_votes, then you should not use a loop. Because there is only one object there.

```
    public ActionResult ps_formForty(candidate_votes cand )
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> data2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data2.Add("cmember_id", (cand.cmember_id).ToString());
            data2.Add("cparty_id", cand.cparty_id.ToString());
            data2.Add("cand_votos", cand.cand_votos.ToString());
            DbObject.Insert("candidate_votes", data2);

        return View();
}
```

If what you want is the number of letters in the cmember_id, then use `cmember_id.Length` instead of `cmember_id.count`.

Comment: but the problem is that i want like this ..... the code is same as it is but i cannot apply loop that,s my question how i can apply loop like this and i want like this code i have written ... i think you understand what i am saying !

Comment: Okay.. Only now noticed, candidate_votes  is not a collection as @stephen_muecke says. You can only loop a collection and not a simple class. You need to return an array from the UI.

Comment: So how i can post an array to controller ??

Comment: I have edited the earlier answer to reflect the changes. Do check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just placed index in view for array of object
Then get list of object from your action method.

@Model  System.Generic.Collection.List

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@*Note : Replace Your Controller Name*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("ps_formForty", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var doc in Model)
    {
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Candidate Name</label>
                <p>@doc.member_name</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="list[@i].cmember_id" value="@doc.cmember_id" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Party Name</label>
                <p>@doc.party_name</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="list[@i].cparty_id" value="@doc.cparty_id" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Total Votes</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cand_votos[@i]" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        i++;
    }
    <input type="submit">
}



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ps_formForty(List<candidate_votes> cand)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> data2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in cand)
        {
            data2.Add("cmember_id", (item.cmember_id).ToString());
            data2.Add("cparty_id", item.cparty_id.ToString());
            data2.Add("cand_votos", item.cand_votos.ToString());
            DbObject.Insert("candidate_votes", data2);

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: **@Model System.Generic.Collection.List** i have add this model to view but when i submit form error **Object Cand Reference is Null **
        foreach (var item in **cand**)
        {
            
        }

Comment: Please compare below suggestion with your code
1)@Model System.Generic.Collection.List< **yourNameSpace.candidate_votes** >
2)  `<input type="hidden" name="**list[@i].cparty_id**" value="@doc.cparty_id" class="form-control" />`